# Magento API for mobile application

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

My organization wants to create **mobile application** for their **website**

I have checked the **rest API** from dev docs:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/rest_front.html

**Is it ok to use rest API for mobile? I mean how can I send my home page data to rest API? or how can I send any other custom page developed through API?**

Comment: Magento provides a good document for Rest APIs you can check those from yourwebsitename.com/swagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use magento REST API  service for mobile app integration. ( You have to check the magento [integrations document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html) for the same where its clearly stated "Mobile applications authenticate using tokens."  )

In default magento, We have web services for catalog, customer, cart and orders. You have to follow the below ways to share the data to mobile app.

***Home Page / Custom Pages***

Having entire page html to mobile app is not good idea. You have to share needed meta information ( banners, promotional data like new arrivals, best sellers ) as JSON data to mobile app. Mobile app needs to construct the home page/custom pages accordingly based on web service data.

Comment: Thanks Thamo for clearing things